# Semantic ui accordion into modal

Tags: css, accordion, semantic-ui

**EDIT:**
found problem, but no know how to fix. There is a problem with semant.js and jquery.ui.js

**error**: http://jsfiddle.net/taioli/tg21uLoh/12/

**correct**(without jquery.ui) http://jsfiddle.net/taioli/tg21uLoh/11/

i don't understant this problem. i have an accordion into a modal that doesn't work. First of all i thought that there is a css conflict, but, after some 
evidence that I did, there isn't css conflict.

**modal**

```
<div class="ui modal history">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Profile Picture
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="ui accordion">
            <div class="title">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                What is a dog?
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="transition ">A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and faithfulness, it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                What kinds of dogs are there?
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="transition hidden">There are many breeds of dogs. Each breed varies in size and temperament. Owners often select a breed of dog that they find to be compatible with their own lifestyle and desires from a companion.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="title ">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                How do you acquire a dog?
            </div>
            <div class="content ">
                <p class="transition ">Three common ways for a prospective owner to acquire a dog is from pet shops, private owners, or shelters.</p>
                <p class="transition ">A pet shop may be the most convenient way to buy a dog. Buying a dog from a private owner allows you to assess the pedigree and upbringing of your dog before choosing to take it home. Lastly, finding your dog from a shelter, helps give a good home to a dog who may not find one so readily.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui black deny button">
            Nope
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
            Yep, that's me
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

in document ready

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion();

$('.ui.modal.history').modal('show');
```

i try this in a jsfiddle and it's work. In my page i have this
[image]

the first item actually doesn't work.

**The strangest thing is that in a identically jsfiddle it's work**

Comment: Any log in console ?

Comment: nothing, no error

Comment: Can you give the fiddle for compare with your picture please ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taioli/tg21uLoh/11/

Comment: in my page the first item doesn'work, also

Comment: What do you load with semantic.js/.css on your environnement?

Comment: i download compontents with bower, i load it in my folder, version 2.2.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142497/discussion-between-cyril-beeckman-and-taioli-francesco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic.js and jQuery-ui.js have the same function `'Accordion'`

Just take a look at https://jqueryui.com/download/

Create your own customized jquery-ui library and don't check the component `accordion`.

It will probably solve your bug.

Comment: for everyone that have this problem, i open an issue. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5304